# Bash delete a file excluding under a directory or subdirectory containing certain name pattern

Tags: bash, shell

The file structure:

```
|-- ./a
|   |-- ./a/b
|   |   `-- ./a/b/file.json
|   `-- ./a/file.json
|-- ./file.json
|-- ./folder
|   `-- ./folder/file.json
|-- ./guides
|   `-- ./guides/file.json
|-- ./network
|   |-- ./network/file.json
|   `-- ./network/guides
|       `-- ./network/guides/file.json
`-- ./script.sh

6 directories, 8 files
```

When running the script, it should delete `file.json` file from every directory excluding the one with a "guides" name.

So the output should give:

```
|-- ./a
|   `-- ./a/b
|-- ./file.json
|-- ./folder
|-- ./guides
|   `-- ./guides/file.json
|-- ./network
|   `-- ./network/guides
|       `-- ./network/guides/file.json
`-- ./script.sh

6 directories, 4 files
```

My attempt to write code:

```sh
for directory in $(find . -maxdepth 40 -type d)
do
    if [[ ${directory##*/} != "guides" && ${directory##*/} != "." ]]
    then
        find ${directory##*/} -name "*file.json" -type f -delete
    fi
done
```

INCORRECT output of my code:

```
|-- ./a
|   `-- ./a/b
|-- ./file.json
|-- ./folder
|-- ./guides
|   `-- ./guides/file.json
|-- ./network
|   `-- ./network/guides
`-- ./script.sh

6 directories, 3 files
```

However this code does not work as expected.

What's the fix?

EDIT:

`./guides/network/file.json` file.json in this path should also be deleted.

Comment: Should a file with a path like `./guides/network/file.json` (i.e. one where `guides` is not the immediate parent of the `file.json` file) be deleted?

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds several problems with the code.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that the `network` directory is neither `guides` nor `.` so a recursive delete is done on it.  (Skipping the recursive delete on `network/guides` doesn't help.)

Comment: @pjh I haven't ran into `./guides/network/file.json` this scenario but if that would be the case of me wanting to delete file.json on such paths, how would the code look like?

Currently, dan's answer is closest and works fine but it does not cover above scenario I think.

Could you please comment the solution?

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -type f -name file.json -not -path '*/guides/file.json' -exec rm -f {} +
```

- `-path` is POSIX find, but it was added after 2004
- `*` in a `-path` argument can match slashes
- `rm -v` (logging) may be useful if your rm supports it

edit: find and delete all files named `file.json`, but *do not descend* any directory named `guides`:

```
find . -type d -name guides -prune \
    -o -type f -name file.json -exec rm -f {} +
```

- If the file is a directory is called `guides`, we use `-prune` to not descend in to it.
- Otherwise, test for a file named `files.json`, and remove it.

Comment: Thank you. I know this wasnt originally asked but if for the path, `./guides/network/file.json`, I want to delete file.json then?

Could you please add another command?

Comment: See the edit, I think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
find . -type d -name guides -prune -o -type f -name file.json -exec rm -- {} +
```

See [Delete all files except in a certain subdirectory with find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87258/264812) for an explanation of why `-exec rm ...` has to be used instead of `-delete`.